# why the active state of bootstrap navbar item changes after page load is complete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

i have bootstrap `navbar` with `navbar` text items on it. In my `action methods (MVC)` i have put the following code to highlight (or make active) the clicked item on `navbar`

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.navbar-menu-item', function (evt) {

                var cat = $(this).text();

                if (cat=='TV & Audio')
                {
                    $('#navbar li').removeClass('active');
                    $('a:contains("TV & Audio")').parent().addClass('active');
                }
                else if (cat=='Cameras')
                {
                    $('#navbar li').removeClass('active');
                    $('a:contains("Cameras")').parent().addClass('active');
                }
            });
         });
   </script>
}
```

once the page is loaded the '`active`' jumps back to the previous active item. By default i have set the `'Home'` item as active in the `_layout.cshtml`. The main action method that calls all the pages has the above `js` code. When click the `navbar` item, for that moment it shows active but after it completes the page load it makes "Home" active again. Is there away to fix this?

Comment: Your setting the `active` class in the current view. As soon as you redirect and reload the page its generating the original html, not what you modified in the previous page. You need to pass a value to the view indicating which item you want to be marked as active (say using a `ViewBag` property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay, how do i use that passed value to mark the clicked item as active?

Comment: You have not shown your html, but you could give each link a `id` attribute and in the controller add `ViewBag.Active = "xxx"` where `xxx` matches the `id` that you want to mark as active. Then in `document.ready`, remove the `active` class from the "Home" link and find the link matching the `ViewBag.Active` value and set its class - say `$('#@ViewBag.Active').addClass('active');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke also one could save the categoryId to a hidden field : )